# Css not loading in YII2

Tags: php, yii2

I implemented pretty URLs in YII2, everything worked fine before implementation, but now loads the styles of my app. Can I lend a hand please?

My manin.php

```
'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '<alias:index|login|logout|contact|about|signup|request-password-reset|reset-password>' => 'site/<alias>',
            '<alias:index|create|confirm|confirmation|update|delete>' => 'user/<alias>',
        ],
    ],
```

Request.php

```
<?php
namespace common\components;
class Request extends \yii\web\Request {
    public $web;
    public $adminUrl;

    public function getBaseUrl(){
        return str_replace($this->web, "", parent::getBaseUrl()) . $this->adminUrl;
    }


/*
    If you don't have this function, the admin site will 404 if you leave off
    the trailing slash.

    E.g.:

    Wouldn't work:
    site.com/admin

    Would work:
    site.com/admin/

    Using this function, both will work.
*/
public function resolvePathInfo(){
    if($this->getUrl() === $this->adminUrl){
        return "";
        }else{
            return parent::resolvePathInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php


 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: To ensure that you should added following line in config file..          ` `'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
     'class' => 'app\components\Request',
         'web'=> '/web',
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'JDqkJaMgIITAKcsJY6yvLQdM9jf7WghX',
        ],`

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php`